Per the Rambam, why does the borrower who repaid interest not receive lashes?
The Rambam (מלוה ולוה 4:1)  explains why, despite when borrowing and lending with interest one transgresses a לאו, one does not receive lashes -

אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהַמַּלְוֶה וְהַלּוֶֹה עוֹבְרִין עַל כָּל אֵלּוּ הַלָּאוִין אֵינָן לוֹקִין עָלָיו מִפְּנֵי שֶׁנִּתָּן לְהִשָּׁבוֹן. שֶׁכָּל הַמַּלְוֶה בְּרִבִּית אִם הָיְתָה רִבִּית קְצוּצָה שֶׁהִיא אֲסוּרָה מִן הַתּוֹרָה הֲרֵי זוֹ יוֹצְאָה בְּדַיָּנִין וּמוֹצִיאִין אוֹתָהּ מִן הַמַּלְוֶה וּמַחְזִירִין לַלּוֶֹה. וְאִם מֵת הַמַּלְוֶה אֵין מוֹצִיאִין מִיַּד הַבָּנִים:
Although the lender and the borrower violate all the negative commandments mentioned above, they are not punished with lashes, because the interest must be returned. For whenever a person gives a loan at interest, if fixed interest is involved, it is forbidden by Scriptural Law and may be expropriated through legal process. The judges expropriate it from the lender and return it to the borrower. If the lender dies, it is not expropriated from his children's possessions.

Presumably, this works with the concept of לאו הניתק לעשה.
This makes sense for the lender, as he has an obligation to return the interest. But how does this concept apply to the borrower, who has no obligation to repay, he is just on the receiving end.
The leches mishna touches on this subject by proposing that this is what the other poskim who argue, as mentioned in the Maggid Mishne, hold

ויש לחלוק על זה ולומר דדוקא מלוה וערב דאינהו מחזירין הממון פטורים אבל לוה דאינו מחזיר כלל חייב **ואפשר דהיינו מ"ש ה"ה ויש מדקדק בהיפך כלומר **דדוקא מלוה וערב כדכתיבנא

I am looking for an explanation of the Rambam.

Presumably the borrower has an obligation to claw back the interest through beis din, like the Rambam prescribes. (If he was just referring to the lender's remedy, why even mention הֲרֵי זוֹ יוֹצְאָה בְּדַיָּנִין?)

But see Even Haazel who differentiates between נתן להשבון and לאו הניתק לעשה.

@shmosel thanks for the even haezel, I was wondering if such a thought exists. I will explore it
